# how to launch an activity via notification received by GCM and set text in that activitiy android?

Tags: android, push-notification

I have developed an app in which I used GCM service to get notification, now when I received notification I want to launch an activity and in that activity I have to set a text received by GCM to a textview.My problem is that the activity which is getting launch by tapping on notification is able to set text only when the app is in foreground but not when the app is in background.

here is the code snippet I used.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
 private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
  int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
  long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
  NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
    .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

  String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

  // Intent notificationIntent = new
  // Intent().setClassName("com.ninehertz.bella",
  // "com.ninehertz.bella.BellaNotificationActivity");
  Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,
    BellaNotificationActivity.class);
  // set intent so it does not start a new activity
  notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
  PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
    notificationIntent, 0);
  notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
  notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

  // Play default notification sound
  notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

  // notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" +
  // context.getPackageName() + "your_sound_file_name.mp3");

  // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
  notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
  notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

 }
```

Comment: for that you will have to bring the activity on front, when you startActivity it comes to front I guess

Comment: what should I do for that?

Comment: where you starting your activity pass text as extra and in that activity's onCreate get that value and set that to textView if your activity is coming to front with a view, that should work

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
            .setContentTitle("My notification")
            .setContentText("Hello World!");
    // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);

   //put your extra message from notification and get from bundes in in onCreate in    ResultActivity
    resultIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,message);

    // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
    // started Activity.
    // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
    // your application to the Home screen.
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(ResultActivity.class);
    // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                0,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
    mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code.I have no problem whether the app in foreground or background.

```
private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
         //NotificationActivity will be called when tapping notification
     Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationActivity.class);
              //this message will be carried away to NotificationActivity and you can setetxt
              notificationIntent.putExtra("msg",message);
              notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
              Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
       PendingIntent intent =PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


             NotificationCompat.Builder noti =  new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(" New message ")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.city)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
            .setContentIntent(intent);
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            noti.setAutoCancel(true);
            notificationManager.notify(001,noti.build());
           }
```